# Flutter Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Error: Unsupported operation: Platform._operatingSystem
dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 294:49      throw*
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/io_patch.dart 244:5                   _operatingSystem
dart-sdk/lib/io/platform_impl.dart 56:40                                          get operatingSystem
dart-sdk/lib/io/platform.dart 83:44                                               get operatingSystem
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 1220:8  get
dart-sdk/lib/io/platform.dart 156:50                                              get isAndroid
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 1220:8  get
packages/city_bank_merchantapp/screen/login/loginscreen.dart 529:20               getDeviceDetails
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 127:5                _async
packages/city_bank_merchantapp/screen/login/loginscreen.dart 523:47               getDeviceDetails
packages/city_bank_merchantapp/screen/login/loginscreen.dart 74:5                 initState